# How do I use an IF statement in Excel where I'm comparing to a list?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'd like to place a value in another column based on data in a field.

If B2 = "UBE" or "APPL" or "TBLE" then the value should be 3 else 1

I can't seem to specify the "list" of values.

`=IF(B2=UBE,3,1)` is what I have now, and it still won't work just on ONE value.

Comment: Note that you specify D2 in the second sentence and B2 in your example.  Also, text strings need to be in quotes.  Either of those problems might explain why your single value formula isn't working.

Comment: So just to expand on what @fix explained, you need to use double quotes in your formula `=IF(B2="UBE",3,1)` for it to work with just ONE value

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of ways to do this.

- One is to use OR to expand the list of conditions:

  `=IF(OR(B2="UBE",B2="APPL",B2="TBLE"),3,1)`
- Another way is to look for the cell value in a list, which allows you to maintain the list in one place.  Say you put your list in A1:

  A1:  `UBE,APPL,TBLE`

  That string is just data and can only be text, so you don't need to enclose it in quotes there, like is required if you are using it as a comparison value inside a formula, like the one above.  The value in B2 is what you want to test, so your formula could be:

  `=IF(ISERROR(FIND(B2,$A$1)),1,3)`

  If the value of B2 isn't in the list, it will produce an error, so that's the condition for the IF test.  You can also use SEARCH instead of FIND, the difference being that FIND is case-sensitive and SEARCH is not.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify your list of possible matches as an array argument in the MATCH function.

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B2,{"UBE","APPL","TBLE"},0)),1,3)
```

This formula will see if B2 matches any of the values in the array. If it does match one of the values, `MATCH` will return the index of the value that matches. If it does not, `MATCH` will return an error.

`ISERROR` then is used to turn these match results into TRUE or FALSE -- TRUE if `MATCH` returned an error, FALSE if it did not.

`IF` then returns 1 if `ISERROR` is true and 3 if it is false.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to search for the below string stored in A1 as

> `A1=Lemon`

Your list is stored in cells B1, B2 and B3 as below

> `B1=Apple`, 
>   `B2=Banana`, 
>   `B3=Lemon`

You can search for `A1` in the list `B1:B3` (represented as an array) using the below:

> `=IF(SUM(IF(A1=B1:B3,3,0))=0,1,SUM(IF(A1=B1:B3,3,0)))`

Note that this formula needs to be "Enter"ed as an array formula by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. For each match found in the list, value 3 is returned. Assuming that the list comprises of unique values, this will return a 3 if found in the list or 0 if not found in the list. If 0, then replace it with 1.